# How can I find ranges of values out of low and high bounds?

Tags: sql, database

I'm currently trying to find ranges of values given list of bounds.
Here is some example data:

| # | Low | High |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 8 |
| 2 | 3 | 8.1 |
| 3 | 3.2 | 8 |
| 4 | 3.1 | 8.2 |
| 5 | 3.4 | 5 |
| 6 | 3.3 | 5 |
| 7 | 3.2 | 5.2 |
| 8 | 3.4 | 5.1 |
| 9 | 3.6 | 5 |
| 10 | 3.5 | 5.7 |
| 11 | 6 | 8 |
| 12 | 6.2 | 8.1 |
| 13 | 6.1 | 8.3 |

Here, I wanna find 3 ranges :

| # start | # end | Low | High |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 3 | 8 |
| 5 | 9 | 3.2 | 5.2 |
| 11 | 13 | 6 | 8.3 |

I have way more values in reality so there will be more ranges (and longer), but the basics are here.
The data is in an sql database, so doing processing in an SQL query would be awesome. If not, an algorithm would do.

I've tried checking each data with the next, but it didn't really turn out okay...

Comment: Can you share your table definition ? is this table contains two rows only ?

Comment: low and high are actually the 2 columns, and there are a lot of rows (there's actually more columns but not related to this problem)

Comment: Can you update your question by adding the expected output from the simple data you have shared

Comment: Sorry, I can't see any connection between the data provided and the numbers you want to find. In fact the numbers `1`, `4`, `9`, `11` and `13` are not even IN your data.

Comment: Are you looking to include ranges that partially overlap your criteria, ranges that fully encompass your criteria, ranges that are fully encompassed by your criteria, ranges that exactly match your criteria, or ranges outside the bounds of your criteria?

Comment: It looks like the order is given and the ranges are in the form [fromIndex, toIndex] 1-based. Yes we need to define some measurement and a tolerance to decide if it still belongs to the same range.

Comment: @phatfingers The goal is to find ranges from the values. ie if you "plot" them, you can clearly visually see some low and high bounds forming a "rectangle" (a range). I think there should be some allowance as to including lines in a range if it's only slightly different than others

Answer (score 1):

So you have a list with bounds and want to find ranges of similar bounds? I think in your case a pretty simple algorithm would do, but I don't see how this can be written as an SQL query.

Define a tolerance, in your case 1 seems to be a good choice. Then for each element do:

1. If first element or a new range starts set minLower and maxLower to the lower bound minUpper and maxUpper to the upper bound and save the index as the start of the range. Then proceed with the next element.
2. If the lower bound is smaller than minLower set minLower to the lower bound and if the lower bound is higher than maxLower set maxLower to the lower bound. Do the same for the upper bound and minUpper, maxUpper.
3. Now if maxLower - minLower > tolerance or maxUpper - minUpper > tolerance you start a new range, so set the end of the current range to the previous index and proceed with 1. Otherwise go to the next element and proceed with 2.

Don't forget to close the range in the end. This works with absolute difference, could also use relative difference, e.g. the max of lower bound can be 10% bigger than the min of lower bound.